# Is it possible to use a wildcard (*) in the <Files> tag of .htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

For poorly configured Apache servers you can have to do something like this to deny access to the .htaccess file:

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

Now is it possible to use a wildcard in the filename? I would like to deny access to all system files (.* - any file that it's filename starts with a dot). I would like to know if the following would work for what I want:

```
<Files .*>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need there is `FilesMatch`:

```
<FilesMatch "^\.">
    [config]
</FilesMatch>
```

(The pattern is a regexp, rather than a glob, though).

[More Info here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#filesmatch)

Comment: Would <FilesMatch "^\."> be better?

Comment: Actually, yes. My regex `\..*` doesn't anchor at the start of the line, which would be pretty messy for most web sites :) Fixed.

Comment: Yeah it's what I tought ;)